# Is there a rule of thumb for what a bing map's zoom setting should be based on how many miles you want to display?

Tags: design, algorithms

If a map contains pushpins/waypoints that span only a couple of miles, the map should be zoomed way in and show a lot of detail. If the pushpins/waypoints instead cover vast areas, such as hundreds or even thousands of miles, it should be zoomed way out.

That's clear. My question is: is there a general guideline for mapping (no pun intended) Bing Maps zoom levels to a particular number of miles that separate the furthest apart points? e.g., is there some chart that has something like:

Zoom level N shows 2 square miles
Zoom level N shows 5 square miles
etc.?

Answer (score 2):

[ViewOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx) lets you specify the view using the bounds, rather than a center and a zoom.  That's probably the way to go.  Find the westernmost, southernmost, northernmost and easternmost pushpins and use their coordinates to construct a bounding rectangle.

Comment: Taking into account wrapping of longitude if the use cases are likely to include sets of points in the Pacific.